# Using checkboxes to delete multiple images from db successfully but doesn't unlink files from folder

Tags: php, checkbox, background-image, unlink

I have a problem with the `unlink()` function in PHP. I have used a checkbox for deleting images or uploded video files.

Multiple images or videos are deleted sucessfully from the database but not from the local folder using `unlink()`.

There are no errors but when I select all checkboxes and press delete then all files from the database are deleted but only the first file is unlinked.

this is my code:

```
<?php // for delete checked video php script

include('config.php');

if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $checkedCandidates = 0;
    $id = implode(",", $_POST['deletecb']);

    $checkedCandidates = count($id);

    if ($checkedCandidates < 1) {
        echo "<div id=\"errormsg\"> You need to check at least one video for delete. </div>";
        echo "<script>setTimeout(\"location.href = 'video_upload.php';\",3000);</script>";
    } else {
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * FROM video_gallery where id_vid IN($id) and users_name='$login_session'");

        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $fname=$row[FILE_NAME];

            $Path="data/58f60f2e09f07_jay/videos/$fname";
            if (file_exists($Path)){
                if (unlink($Path)) {
                    echo "success";
                } else {
                    echo "fail";
                }
            } else {
                echo "file does not exist";
            }
        }
        $query1=mysqli_query($connection,"delete from video_gallery where id_vid IN($id) and users_name='$login_session'");
        if($query1) {
            echo "<div id=\"successmsg\"> delete successfully </div>";
        } else {
            echo "<div id=\"errormsg\"> failed operation!!</div>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `print_r($row);` 
and check the key name of the file name
change this line as you are accessing an array item

```
$fname=$row[FILE_NAME];
```

to

```
$fname=$row['the actual name of the field'];
```

Comment: thank its done...field name is right but i missing ' ' like this $fname=$row[FILE_NAME]; and solved using ' ' $fname=$row['FILE_NAME'];

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$Path="data/58f60f2e09f07_jay/videos/$fname";` with `$Path="data/58f60f2e09f07_jay/videos/".$fname;`

and replace `$row[FILE_NAME]` with `$row['FILE_NAME']`